# Left outer Join SQL Server Problem - not returning enough rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I've got the following Tables:

```
User 1:n UserFilter n:1 Filter
```

`Filter` got an `ID` and a `Name`, `User` got his `Name` as `ID` (don't blame me, not my idea!).

The whole "User 'a' got Filters 1, 2 and 3"-Idea is being used in an ASP frontend, not important for the question.

`UserFilter` simply got 2 columns, `User` and `FilterID`, so if there's a column User a - Filter 1, that means User a is using Filter 1, if there is no such column, it means he's not.

Now I'd like to perform a SELECT query that returns every filter (there are 8 overall) for a specific user with a custom column called `active`.

Here's what I got so far:

```
select 
    distinct f.Name, f.Type, 
    case when uf.userid = 'a' then 1 else 0 end as Active 
from filter f 
left outer join userfilter uf on f.id = uf.filterid
where uf.userid = 'a' or uf.userid is null
```

This will return 8 columns, some of them with `Active = 0` and some with `Active = 1`, just as I wanted, BUT if `UserFilter` contains filters of multiple users, e.g.

```
a - 1
a - 2
b - 3
b - 7
a - 8
```

and I run this query for User "a" the query will only return Filter 1 as active, 2 as active, 4 5 and 6 as inactive and 8 as active, completely leaving out 3 and 7.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition that userid='a' should be a join condition:

```
select 
    distinct f.Name, f.Type, 
    case when uf.userid = 'a' then 1 else 0 end as Active 
from filter f 
    left outer join userfilter uf on f.id = uf.filterid and uf.userid = 'a'
```

Comment: Great, this one works for the current case and all other cases (no other users, other users have the same filters, other users have different filters, current user got 0 filters, etc.)!

Answer (score 1):

You have a where clause including only rows where uf.userid ='a' or null

Try:

```
 select distinct f.Name,f.Type, case when uf.userid is null then 0 else 1 end as Active 
 from filter f left outer join userfilter uf on f.id = uf.filterid
```

Comment: Yes, that's the logic that worked so far, what should I do now?

Comment: If I simply remove the where-clause I will receive the Dataset "User: B, Filter: 3, Active: 0" giving me essentially the right information, but I'd like to receive User: NULL instead of B.

Comment: Yes, that's the point, because of your edit this is my current state. There will be a row "User: B Filter: 3 Active: 0", which is correct, but should display User: NULL instead of B. Furthermore, if I activate Filter '3' for User A too, i receive 2 Rows: User A Filter 3 Active 1 and User B Filter 3 Active 0.

Answer (score 1):

Corina's answer is correct. Here is another way to express the same thing (just to show you a different way to write the same query):

```
select 
    Filter.Name, Filter.[Type],  
    case when x.UserId IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as Active
from 
    Filter
left join
(
    select 
        *
    from 
        UserFilter
    where
        UserFilter.UserId = 'a'
) x
on
    Filter.Id = x.FilterId
```